# iOS Simulator scrolling issue without Rosetta option on Mac M1

Tags: ios, react-native, scroll, ios-simulator, apple-m1

Source of the issue [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668488?page=2) .

I build React-Native application for iOS simulator on Mac with M1 processor. So after all is configured properly ([like this](https://milanpanchal24.medium.com/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios-file-for-8c0cc28ec832)) app runs fine. There is an issue inside - **you cannot scroll properly inside the app screens, no inertia, when you scroll something and then drop the finger it stops instantly. It forces you to lead with finger every pixel and watch all content very slow.**

It was fixed with previous Xcode versions by "Open using Rosetta" flag in Simulator configs. But with new versions of Xcode simulator simply **doesn't have option "Open using Rosetta"**.

With Xcode 14.2 I tried to call ios simulator in command line by

```
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
```

It doesn't fix the issue.

Does anyone know how to run iOS simulator in Rosetta mode for Xcode 14.2 for instance where no Rosetta support on simulators?
Or maybe anyone knows how fix scrolling issue on Simulator on M1 w/o using Rosetta?

Comment: This sounds like it should be a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Running Xcode and / or simulator in Rosetta is not supported now.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found out that this scrolling issue is because the simulator was forced to run in Rosetta mode. If you have Excluded Architectures set for your project to exclude arm64, I suggest you remove that (you might have to update your pods/packages to new versions that support Apple Silicon architecture).
Once that setting is removed, that smooth scrolling will come back.